# RN camera realy slow

Tags: javascript, react-native, camera, hook

I am using react-native-camera-hooks in my app, but it takes forever to get a photo from the camera. In the code below, **takePicture()** promise takes **about 15 seconds to resolve**. It takes no time to take photo from native camera on the same phone. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    import { useCamera } from 'react-native-camera-hooks'
    
    const [{cameraRef}, {takePicture}] = useCamera(null);
    
     const handleCapture = async () => {
            var options = {  base64: true, fixOrientation: true, quality: 0.4, skipProcessing: true };
            try {
                const data = await takePicture(options);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }    
        }
    
     <RNCamera
                    ref={cameraRef}
                    type={cameraType}
                    style={styles.cameraPreview}
                    captureAudio={false}
                    flashMode={flashMode}
                >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleCapture} />
     </RNCamera>
```

Comment: It looks like that library doesn't have that many downloads or maintenance. Any reason why you picked that one?

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-native-vision-camera`. It is the best package for camera in React Native.

https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera